# Collapsing unions in mypy

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a piece of code written around a field, called `data` that has a type of `Dict[str, Union[List[str], str]]`. The issue is that the mypy is raising errors:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Union

data: Dict[str, Union[List[str], str]] = {}

key = "a"
value = "b"
if isinstance(data[key], list):
    data[key].append(value)  # Item "str" of "Union[List[str], str]" has no attribute "append"
else:
    temp = data[key]
    data[key] = [temp, value]  # List item 0 has incompatible type "Union[List[str], str]"; expected "str"
```

In other typed languages, I would expect this to work. I've clearly boxed the type to a list in the first branch of the if-statement, so `self._data[key]` should resolve to `List[str]` and `append` should be fine. Similarly, in the else-branch, `self._data[key]` should resolve to `str`, meaning that `temp` is `str` and therefore should not cause any issues being added to a `List[str]`.

Does anyone see a way to fix this without adding unnecessary type assertions here?

Comment: Please add the full class definition to your question.

Comment: What errors are you referring to?

Comment: @MadPhysicist They're mypy errors and I've included them as code comments

Comment: @binaryescape Adding a full class definition would add no value to the question and could only serve to make it less clear. What I have done is annotated the type so that you can tell exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract `self._data[key]` to a local variable before the type guards:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Union

# "self._data"
data: Dict[str, Union[List[str], str]] = {}

key = "a"
value = "b"

current_value = data[key]
if isinstance(current_value, list):
    current_value.append(value)
else:
    data[key] = [current_value, value]
```

This passes type checking with `mypy --strict`.

Mypy can't assume that `self._data[key]` always evaluates to the same type, even with the same key. For all it knows, `self._data` is actually a complex user-defined subclass, which could return different union variants semi-randomly, or even rebind `self._data` or `key` to different objects.

Comment: If you need this to work in `elif` condition, walrus operator can be handy (`elif isinstance(current_value := data[key], Something): ...`) to avoid unnecessary key lookup.